# Making multiple vectors from one vector of random doubles

Tags: c++, c++11, random, vector

I am generating a vector of 20,000 random numbers (doubles) and I would like, in addition to putting the number in this vector, called A here, to also copy all numbers between 0.0 and 0.1 into a separate vector. When I try to do this, my compiler (latest g++ version) gives me these errors:

```
"error: request member 'begin' in 'r0', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<double>()' for (it0=r0.begin(); it0!=r0.end();++it0)"

"error: request member 'end' in 'r0', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<double>()' for (it0=r0.begin(); it0!=r0.end();++it0)"

"error: request for member 'emplace_back' in 'r0', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<double>()' r0.emplace_back(A[i]);"
```

I am a relative novice in C++, but I thought that the vector data structure had methods/member functions called .begin() and .end() that help access it using iterators. It seems to me that the compiler doesn't see my vector as a vector? I'm really not sure, but below is what I did:

I have linked: iostream, cmath, fstream, time.h, cstdlib, vector, stdio.h, cstdio, iomainip, algorithm (in that order)

Here is the code I have now:

```
int main() {
double N=20000; 
std::vector<double> A(N+1); 
std::vector<double> r0(); 
std::vector<double>::iterator it0;

std::srand((unsigned)time(0));

for(double i = 0; i<(N+1); ++i) {
    double high = 1.0, low = 0.0;
    A[i]=((double) rand()/(static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX) + 1.0))*(high - low)+low;

    for(it0=r0.begin(); it0!=r0.end(); ++it0) { 
            if(0.0<=A[i] && A[i]<0.1) { //NOTE:post-incrementing creates an unnecessary temporary iterator 
        rand1.emplace_back(A[i]);                        
        count0++;           
            }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

The point of this is that I will place all of the numbers in vector A into bins of size 0.1 each, starting from 0.0, and then plot them in a histogram using gnuplot to assess the uniformity of the random numbers (generated using the pseudorandom number generator that comes with linux mint). 
Also, I wanted to ask what the advantages of .emplace_back() are over .push_back(). Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it as I am at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<double> r0();
```

This is parsed as a function taking no argument and returning `std::vector<double>`. This is called [*most vexing parse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) error. There is also error in your loop. Together, this should read:

```
std::vector<double> r0;

for( int i = 0; i < N+1; ++i) { 
            if(0.0<=A[i] && A[i]<0.1) {
            //...          
            }
}
```

Comment: That's got it working! I ended up using an iterator to go through the vector and print its elements to a txt file, but I've moved that loop outside of the one that actually generates both the large vector, A, and the smaller vector r0. Should've realized that I was looping over an empty vector lol. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<double> r0();
```

You've fallen victim to the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) (although this case is arguably not as *vexing* as the linked example). The line above defines a function named `r0` that takes no arguments, and returns an `std::vector<double>` by value. Get rid of the trailing parentheses and your code should compile.

---

Another oddity in your code is that you say you want to generate 20,000 random numbers, but you're generating 20,001. You don't need the `N+1` you keep using, replace that by `N`.

And as [lizusek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141471/lizusek) points out in the comments, you're pointlessly iterating over an empty vector (`r0`) in the statement below:

```
for(it0=r0.begin(); it0!=r0.end(); ++it0) { // this loop is never entered
```

---

Finally, you should'nt be using `rand()` and friends anymore, C++11 provides far superior random number generation facilities in the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header. I'd rewrite your code as

```
std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
    A[i] = dis(gen);

    if(A[i] > 0 && A[i] < 0.1) {
      // add this to the r0 vector
      r0.push_back(A[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: worse oddity is iterating empty vector instead of iterating A: it0=r0.begin(); it0!=r0.end(); ++it0

Comment: Thank you both, that's got it! I really wish I could upvote everyone who answered, but I'm still new to the site. Still, thank you so much! One more quick thing: in order for it to compile, I had to replace r0.emplace_back(A[i]) with r0.push_back(A[i]). Do you know why it didn't like the first way? Also, thank you for the link!

Comment: @user3399925 [They should both work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8259167d7b80aab8). What error are you getting with `emplace_back`?

Comment: @Praetorian "error: 'class std::vector<double>' has no member named 'emplace_back' r0.emplace_back(A[i]);"

Comment: @user3399925 What version of g++ are you using? And are you passing the `-std=c++11` switch to the compiler?

Comment: @Praetorian it says 4.8.1. I haven't seen -std=c++11 before. What does it do and where would I place it?

Comment: @user3399925 That switch is need to enable C++11 features, otherwise g++ compiles in C++03 mode by default. You pass it on the compiler command line just like other arguments. For example: *g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp*

Comment: Nice! For some reason, I thought that it would automatically compile in C++11. That would've taken me a while to figure out - it works perfectly fine, thank you!